# Redirect to trailng slash (htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Trying to add a trailing slash to every link. For instance:

```
http://testsite.com/products
```

should `301 redirect` to:

```
http://testsite.com/products/
```

etc. But how? Here is my current `.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|css|js|txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/migrate
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/install
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `RewriteRule !/$ /$0/ [L,R=301]` suffice?

Comment: Hi it works, but now my 404 error page is not displayed